# #define and invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘double’)

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Just started programming C++, and stuck on the code below. On Ubuntu terminal I try to compile with

```
g++ -o circleArea circleArea.cpp
```

I get the error:

```
circleArea.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
circleArea.cpp:14:14: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘double’)
  area = PI * r * r;
              ^
```

The code is :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define PI 3.14159;
#define newLine "\n";

int main(void)
{
    double r;
    double area;
    cout << "Please enter the radius : ";
    cin >> r;
    area = PI * r * r;
    cout << "Area is " << area << " unit squares" << newLine;   
}
```

If replace the line "area = PI * r * r" with "area = 3.14159 * r * r" I don't get any errors. What is the problem, can you help?

Thank you

Comment: What do you think `area = PI; * r * r;` does?

Comment: Trying to calculate the area with PI * r * r, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `#define PI 3.14159;`,

```
area = PI * r * r;
```

becomes

```
area = 3.14159; * r * r;
```

Note the extra `;` between `3.14159` and `* r`. It's like

```
area = 3.14159;
* r * r;
```

and thus the first `*` is treated as a unary dereference operator.
You should remove the semicolon in the end of macro definition.